# amazon s3 bucket upload images curl exception 'data rewind wasn't possible '

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using codeigniter to upload images to a amazon storage bucket.Iam getting this error and i dont know what to do to overcome this problem

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' with message '[curl] 65: necessary data rewind wasn't possible [url] https://public-ww-lk.s3.amazonaws.com/images/gallery/the-kingsbury-colombo-sri-lanka-21401-293x154.jpg' in E:\projects\wwlk\application\third_party\Awsmy\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti.php:338 Stack trace: #0 E:\projects\wwlk\application\third_party\Awsmy\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti.php(279): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->isCurlException(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlHandle), Array) #1 E:\projects\wwlk\application\third_party\Awsmy\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti.php(244): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->processResponse(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlHandle), Array) #2 E:\projects\wwlk\application\third_party\Awsmy\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti.php(227): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->processMessages() #3 E:\pro in E:\projects\wwlk\application\third_party\Awsmy\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient.php on line 285

Comment: Check out this link, it may be of some help. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/140

Answer (score 0):

Try setting **CURL** option `body_as_string` to `true`.

Something like this:

```
<?php

$client->getConfig()->set('curl.options', array('body_as_string' => true));
```